# set a Module property only once

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, module

I have a `Module` like this :

```
var Module = (function() {

var id;

var setID = function(a){
    if(a)
     id = a;
    else 
     id = undefined;
};

var getID = function(){
    return id;
};
// Return the object that is assigned to Module
return {
    setID: setID,
    getID: getID
};
}());
```

In which I'm setting the `id` `member` through `setID()` `function`.

I was wondering: in this way, `setID` is a `public` member of my Module, and it can be called by every other `Module` inside my application. I would set `id` only once, and so avoid other call of `setID()` to set is value that must be setted only once.  Is there a way?

I'm new to `Module` *design pattern* so please excuse me for any nubbishness.

Comment: delete this.setID inside the setID function. or if you don't need IE8, you can use Object.defineProperty()

Comment: Would it be okay to pass the id when the module is defined, or do you need it to be set later?

Comment: I've got to set it later, because I gotta call Module.setID(idvalue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify `setID` to do nothing if the ID is already set:

```
var setID = function(a){
    if(typeof a != 'undefined' && typeof id == 'undefined')
       id = a;
};
```

Then other modules could still call it, but it would do nothing (or you could make it throw an error or return `false` instead).

Comment: I figured out this solution just some minutes ago.. but instead of checking the `typeof` I used : `if( a && !id )` . Whats the main differences?

Comment: The difference is that your version will do nothing if you try to set the ID to a falsey value (like `false`, `null` or `0`). I was assuming you'd like to allow those values, so I changed the code to reject `undefined` only.

Comment: nope actually I can accept onyl the value that I set initially, no other value is allowed. 
Another question why did not you used === ?

Comment: I was talking about the value you set initially. If you call `setID(0)` the first time, it won't set the id (because `!a` will be `true`). Maybe that's the intention. To answer the other question, I can safely use `==` here because I know `typeof` always returns a string. It might be slightly slower to do so (and it won't pass jslint). You probably know this kind of choice can lead to endless debates...

Comment: yeah lol . I am just curious , I am developing javascript only since couple months. 
Returning to question , how can I be totally sure that setID wont be called if "undefined" or falsey value are passed ?  
Are your conditions enough?

Comment: Your conditions (`!a && !id`) do that, go with them. My version allows `0`, `false` and `null`. @steo

Comment: Actually, I mean `if(a && !id)` @steo